How to make where FindOptionsWhere support query null default
Now
repo.findOneBy({ status: undefined })
repo.findOneBy({ status: null })

The SQL is all
SELECT * FROM user

Expectation
repo.findOneBy({ status: undefined })
// SELECT * FROM user

repo.findOneBy({ status: null })
// SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = null


you can use IsNull()
repo.findOneBy({ status: IsNull() })

